# Setting Date with year, month, day, hour, minute, seconds, and UTC offset values

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time, momentjs

If I had the following values:

```
const year = 1890
const month = 6
const day = 1
const hour = 5
const minute = 50
const second = 0
const utcOffset = -10
```

How do I set either a Javascript date or a momentJS date for
June 1 1890 5:50 (in the morning) with UTC Offset of -10 ?

All I can see in the internet are examples of 
`new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)`.
Which would default to your local timezone but I want to set the timezone manually using numbers like `+8.5` for `+8.5 GMT` etc.

How do I do this for either Date or Moment JS?

Comment: Dates don't have an offset, the host system does. You can't set the offset using javascript, you'll have to use a library for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use moment [`utcOffset`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/):

> Setting the UTC offset by supplying minutes. Note that once you set an offset, it's fixed and won't change on its own (i.e there are no DST rules). If you want an actual time zone -- time in a particular location, like `America/Los_Angeles`, consider [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/).

In your case you can pass `true` as second parameter to make it preserve the time of the day:

> The `utcOffset` function has an optional second parameter which accepts a boolean value indicating whether to keep the existing time of day.
>
> - Passing `false` (the default) will keep the same instant in Universal Time, but the local time will change.
> - Passing `true` will keep the same local time, but at the expense of choosing a different point in Universal Time.
>
> One use of this feature is if you want to construct a moment with a specific time zone offset using only numeric input values

Here a live sample:

```js
const year = 1890
const month = 6
const day = 1
const hour = 5
const minute = 50
const second = 0
const utcOffset = -10

let m = moment([year, month-1, day, hour, minute, second]).utcOffset(utcOffset, true)

console.log(m.format());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Remember that months are 0 indexed.

Comment: The part "*Setting the UTC offset by supplying minutes*" infers that an offset of -10 hours should be passed as -600 (minutes). However, your example shows that -10 is interpreted as hours. There is a further part which says "*If the input is less than 16 and greater than -16, it will interpret your input as hours instead.*" Given that time zones may be as small as 15 minutes and the largest offset is +14:00, a better limit might have been 15, not 16.

Comment: @RobG docs also states that _If the input is less than `16` and greater than `-16`, it will interpret your input as hours instead._.

Comment: @RobG good point! Maybe you can post this on moment's github page and see if library mantainers want to change limit to 15 instead of 16.